# warning: unknown enum constant Status.STABLE

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-9, junit5, intellij-idea2017

In the quest to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696451/using-junit-5-with-java-9) and somehow [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366582/where-should-i-put-unit-tests-when-migrating-a-java-8-project-to-jigsaw), I was trying out to create packages to subdivide `main` and `test` classes and then to make use of compiler with added modules to execute the unit-tests. Not a very good way agreed, but just a hypothetical structure for now.

[image]

Few open questions as I proceeded further were:-

- Add a JDK9 based module to the project.
- Add JUnit5 to the classpath using IntelliJ's shortcut. (lib folder) [`junit-jupiter-api-5.0.0.jar`]

**Q. Note that it brings along the `opentest4j-1.0.0.jar` to the lib/ folder. Why is that so, what is the other jar used for?**

- Add the classes and generate some tests method correspondingly.
- Compile the [sample project](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/tree/master/junit5jdk9trial/) (shared just to draw a picture of the directory structure in use) using the command

  ```
  javac --module-path lib -d "target" $(find src -name "*.java")
  ```

  Results into warnings as -

> ```
> warning: unknown enum constant Status.STABLE   
>   reason: class file for org.apiguardian.api.API$Status not found 
> warning: unknown enum constant Status.STABLE 
> 2 warnings
> ```

***Note***:-

I find the usage of `junit-jupiter` suspicious since if I comment out the code using JUnit and execute the same command, things seem to be working fine.

***Libraries/Tools*** used if that might matter:-

- `junit-jupiter-api-5.0.0` with
- Java version `"9" (build 9+181)`
- IntelliJ `2017.2.5`

**Q. What could be a probable cause to such a warning? Moreover, I am unable to find the `API.Status` in my project and outside the project classes as well.**

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because I wasn't testing with intelliJ, and that is what you're asking about. I also can't find that `org.apiguardian` package any where, so my guess is that it has to do with intelliJ.

Comment: See https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1065 for details.

Comment: @Sormuras Thanks for the link. Though that might answer `org.apiguardian.api` but its still not clear why does including the junit-jupiter to classpath brings along `opentest4j-1.0.0.jar`?

Comment: "JUnit Jupiter API" depends on it. See https://github.com/ota4j-team/opentest4j for the purpose of this _extra_ project/artifact.

Comment: @Sormuras Any idea about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702273/warning-unknown-enum-constant-status-stable/46950496?noredirect=1#comment80850680_46950496) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compilation warning can simply be ignored. Moreover, it won't be appearing anymore starting with the version `5.1.0` (currently in development). It is all explained in [Release Notes](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/release-notes/index.html#release-notes-5.1.0-M2-overall-improvements):

> In 5.0.1, all artifacts were changed to have an *optional* instead of a mandatory dependency on the *@API Guardian* JAR in their published Maven POMs. However, although the Java compiler should ignore missing annotation types, a lot of users have reported that compiling tests without having the *@API Guardian* JAR on the classpath results in warnings emitted by `javac` that look like this:
>
> ```
> warning: unknown enum constant Status.STABLE
> reason: class file for org.apiguardian.api.API$Status not found
> ```
>
> To avoid confusion, the JUnit team has decided to make the dependency to the *@API Guardian* JAR *mandatory* again.

For reference also see:

- [Remove compile dependency on apiguardian-api in Maven POMs](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1065)
- [Reintroduce compile dependency on apiguardian-api in Maven POMs](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1105)

Answer (score 5):

**1) opentest4j**

`opentest4j` is a transitive dependency of `junit-jupiter-api`. See the dependency graph:

```
+--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.1
     +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.0.0
     \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.0.1
```

**2) unknown enum constant Status.STABLE**

You need to add following dependency: `apiguardian-api`.

For example in *Gradle*, you can do it via:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.1'
    testRuntime 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.1'
    testCompileOnly 'org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0'
}
```

But overall, dependency is build-tool-independent, so you can do it in plain IDE without *Gradle*, or *Maven*.

Comment: *transitive dependency*.. But so is `junit-platform-commons`, which is not brought along. Am I getting something wrong there?

Comment: You are adding dependencies via *IntelliJ* - so, maybe the IDE doesn't consider it as important.

Comment: *IDE doesn't consider it as important* that's a strong statement. Any proofs?

Comment: Just guessing. Because transitive dependencies are clear.