# What is the conventional structure of a modular Java 9 (Eclipse) project?

Tags: eclipse, project, projects-and-solutions

As an example, say I have a program named Abc containing one class named Xyz. The code is located in a Git repository containing a single Eclipse project. I've adopted the Maven source directory layout. Before Java 9 the project structure might have looked like this (simplified):

```
Abc.git
|
+---.git
|
+---Abc
    |
    +---.settings
    |
    +---.project
    |
    +---.classpath
    |
    +---src
        |
        +---main
        |   |
        |   +---java (source folder)
        |       |
        |       +---com
        |           |
        |           +---abc
        |               |
        |               +---Xyz.java
        +---test
            |
            +---java (source folder)
                |
                +---com
                    |
                    +---abc
                        |
                        +---XyzTest.java
```

The JUnit tests were typically in the same packages as the production code, but in a different source folder. But now the production code is in a module. A package being tested can't be split into separate modules. Furthermore, some classes under test may reside in packages not exported by their module.

**What is the correct practice in terms of code organization to address these issues?**

This question is not about Maven. What I meant was: Is this the recommended way to do it?

```
Abc.git
|
+---.git
|
+---Abc
    |
    +---.settings
    |
    +---.project
    |
    +---.classpath
    |
    +---src
        |
        +---main
        |   |
        |   +---java
        |       |
        |       +---com.abc (source folder?)
        |           |
        |           +---module-info.java (exports com.abc)
        |           |
        |           +---com
        |               |
        |               +---abc
        |                   |
        |                   +---Xyz.java
        +---test
            |
            +---java
                |
                What goes here?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should I put unit tests when migrating a Java 8 project to Jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366582/where-should-i-put-unit-tests-when-migrating-a-java-8-project-to-jigsaw) or  
Possible duplicate of [Using JUnit 5 with Java 9 without Maven or Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696451/using-junit-5-with-java-9-without-maven-or-gradle)

Comment: Not duplicates.

Comment: Okay, please explain why not?

Comment: Currently, Eclipse supports one module per project, not per source folder. Be also aware of [this bug which has already been fixed and which will be released with the upcoming Oxygen.3 (4.7.3) on March 21, 2018](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525948). May I ask what are the advantages of using modules in your own code?

Comment: Thank you, that's quite useful info. I don't really know what advantages would be. Basically I just thought modules were considered preferrable to not modules the same way generics is preferred to unchecked pre-Java 5 code. To me it's important to do things by the book because I'm perfectionist.