# Java9 Multi-Module Maven Project Test Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, java-9, maven-surefire-plugin, java-platform-module-system

I have a multi-module maven project with three modules `core`, `utils` and `test-utils`

Core has the following dependencies definition

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>my.project</groupId>
   <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>my.project</groupId>
   <artifactId>test-utils</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have added Java 9 `module-info.java` definitions for all three modules and `core`'s looks like this:

```
module my.project.core {
   requires my.project.utils;
}
```

However I cannot figure out how to get `core`'s test classes to be able to see the `test-utils` classes during test execution. When `maven-surefire-plugin` attempts the test run I get class not found.

If I add a `requires my.project.testutils;` to `core`'s `module-info.java`:

```
module my.project.core {
   requires my.project.utils;
   requires my.project.testutils; //test dependency
}
```

Then at compile time I get an error that the `my.project.testutils` module can't be found (presumably because it's only brought in as a test dependency).

How does one work with test dependencies in a Java 9 modular world? For obvious reason's I don't want my main code to pull in test dependencies. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not a Maven maven and haven't used the Surefire plugin, but the `module-info.java` with the two `requires` is definitely the wrong direction. Generally, in Java 9, tests are facilitated by 'patching' a module (Maven and Gradle tend to abstract this away). On another note, it is unclear if you have seen this doc re: toolchains? - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/java9.html

Comment: This doesn't use the Surefire plugin, nor `test` scope (so I won't write it as an answer), but in case this helps, here is a small Java9 example using Maven - https://github.com/codetojoy/WarO_Java_9_Maven

Comment: @MichaelEaster The part over the patching module is correct there, but the toolchain part seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613214/java-9-maven-junit-does-test-code-need-module-info-java-of-its-own-and-wher

Answer (score 5):

With maven and java9, if your `my.project.testutils` is a test scope dependency, you don't need to explicitly include(`requires`) it in the module descriptor.

---

The test dependencies are taken care via the classpath itself. So you can simply remove the `testutils` and it would be patched by maven while executing tests.

```
module my.project.core {
   requires my.project.utils;
}
```

Refer to the [slide 30 pertaining to maven-compiler-plugin.](https://www.slideshare.net/RobertScholte/java-9-and-the-impact-on-maven-projects)

[image]

I would also suggest you take a look at [Where should I put unit tests when migrating a Java 8 project to Jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366582/where-should-i-put-unit-tests-when-migrating-a-java-8-project-to-jigsaw) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366582/where-should-i-put-unit-tests-when-migrating-a-java-8-project-to-jigsaw#comment69959520_41370766) by Robert confirming on the implementation that maven follows.

***Edit***: Created a [sample project](https://github.com/namannigam/jdk9-maventest) drawing an analogy that the main module is same as your `core`, the dependency on `guava` is same as your `utils` and the `junit` dependency is same as your `testutils`.

Comment: The example project is a dead link.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire ya seems like I've migrated the projects, would try and restore..by that time these answers by Sormuras have a good number of sample links - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110023/how-do-you-organize-tests-in-a-modular-java-project/52110406#52110406) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162778/how-can-i-test-a-service-provider-implementation-module-with-junit-5/52168316#52168316).

Comment: Appears to be true for recent versions of Gradle as well. If you declare a `testImplementation`, `testCompileOnly`, or `testRuntimeOnly` dependency, no module import is required.